# Using German characters (ü, ö, ä, etc.) in text analysis (R)

Tags: r, text, character-encoding

I'm doing some text mining in R. The text I want to analyse is in German.

The problem is that German characters aren't displayed correctly either in the text itself or in the results.

I'm working on Mac OS.

I've found similar threads on here and tried out proposed solutions:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE.UTF-8")
```

seems to change the language (i.e. doesn't give an error message) but the characters are still displayed incorrectly, 
e.g. *Erste-Hilfe-Ma\xa7nahmen* instead of *Erste-Hilfe-Maßnahmen*.

```
text <- readLines("Erste Hilfe.txt", encoding="de_DE.UTF-8")
```

Result: *Erste-Hilfe-Ma\xa7nahmen*

```
text <- readLines("Erste Hilfe.txt", encoding="ISO/IEC 8859-15")
```

Result: *Erste-Hilfe-Ma\xa7nahmen*

Do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 5):

It depends a bit on what you want to do with the files but generally `stri_read_lines()` from the package `stringi` does a fine job with umlauts even when encoding is left on `"auto"`

```
library(stringi)

lines <- stri_read_lines("Erste Hilfe.txt", encoding = "auto")
```

If you display the `lines` vector and it still has problems, you can try to detect the encoding:

```
lines_raw <- stri_read_raw("Erste Hilfe.txt")

stri_enc_detect(lines_raw)
```

Output will look something like this:

```
      Encoding Language Confidence
1        UTF-8                1.00
2 windows-1252       de       0.55
3         Big5       zh       0.44
4 windows-1254       tr       0.25
5 windows-1250       hu       0.14
6     UTF-16BE                0.10
7     UTF-16LE                0.10
8      GB18030       zh       0.10
9   IBM424_rtl       he       0.01
```

In this case, I read in a text file in UTF-8 with many umlauts in it and there was no problem for stringi to guess the encoding correctly. But you might want to try a few encodings if the confidence is not quite as high.

I can also display it without any problem in the Console (despite having set locale to en_GB.UTF-8) but in some cases, that might cause a problem. If you want to check if your encoding was really destroyed by reading in the file or if the Console might not be able to display it, you can try to write the lines back to a file and check:

```
stri_write_lines(lines, "Erste Hilfe_new.txt")
```

You could also try to just create a character vector with umlauts and just see if it gets displayed correctly:

```
"äöü"
```

Usually, RStudio above version 0.93 shouldn't have a problem with that though. Hope this helps.

### Edit:

In the comments, it turned out that the source for the text is still available on the internet - I had not considered that possibility. Often encoding problems happen because some editors force a certain encoding when saving a file. If the source is available online though, you can read text directly into R using the `rvest` package:

```
library(rvest)
lines <- read_html("https://www.zeit.de/wissen/2018-10/erste-hilfe-kinder-rotes-kreuz-kurs-ersthelfer-notfall/komplettansicht") %>% 
  html_nodes(".article__item") %>% 
  html_text()

> grep("Maßnahmen", lines, value = TRUE)[1]
[1] "In vielen europäischen Ländern, etwa in Belgien und Dänemark, steht Erste Hilfe spätestens in der Sekundarstufe im Schullehrplan. Auch Großbritannien arbeitet an einem Gesetzesentwurf, der vorsieht, dass Grundschulkindern grundlegende Erste-Hilfe-Maßnahmen beigebracht werden. Die Schülerinnen und Schüler weiterführender Schulen sollen in Zukunft die Reanimation üben, also Beatmung und Herzdruckmassage.\n"
```

Please refer to their documentation to see how you can determine the correct input for `html_nodes`. I usually use the chrome extension selectorgadget.

Comment: Thanks, but the message is "In stri_encode(txt, encoding, "UTF-8") :
  input data \xffffff9f in current source encoding could not be converted to Unicode" and the display this time: Erste-Hilfe-Ma�nahmen. I'm using the latest version of R (not R Studio).

Comment: I mentioned RStudio because that usually gets around the problems displaying umlauts that some Consoles have. For which command do you get the error message? `stri_read_lines()` on auto?

Comment: Yes, stri_read_lines("Erste Hilfe.txt", encoding = "auto"). The result of stri_enc_detect(lines_raw) was "windows-1252" with 0.8 confidence. So I also tried to do "Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "windows-1252")" but the result is still wrong. Thanks for the tip, I will try it in R studio.

Comment: `Sys.setlocale()` should not be necessary! Can you try `lines <- stri_read_lines("Erste Hilfe.txt", encoding = "windows-1252")` and if that doesn't work try to use the second most probably encoding in the list.

Comment: The result of both lines <- stri_read_lines("Erste Hilfe.txt", encoding = "windows-1252") and lines <- stri_read_lines("Erste Hilfe.txt", encoding = "windows-1254") is Erste-Hilfe-Ma§nahmen

Comment: Is it possible to share the file? I never encountered something like that. Is the error/errors systematic? Then you might be able to replace the wrong characters: `stri_replace_all_fixed(lines, "§", "ß")`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Do you mean my source file or R file? My source file is the text copied from https://www.zeit.de/wissen/2018-10/erste-hilfe-kinder-rotes-kreuz-kurs-ersthelfer-notfall. Not sure how I can share it here.

Comment: Ah I see. But if the source is still available on the website you can just copy it again and past it to a new file where you make sure encoding is UTF-8. In Windows it is usually the editor program which causes these problems. A different editor such as Atom might help. Or you webscrape the source directly into R. I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've tried out the first option proposed by @JBGruber (stringi), but it didn't work out.

In the end the combination of the following measures helped:

- Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
- In R Studio changing `File`> `Reopen with Encoding` into `UTF-8`
- Saving the file again explicitly as coded with UTF-8

I've tried out plenty of ways of solving that, including all the above mentioned steps independently, but that one was the only one that helped.